# can I eat a cryovaced cured ham left in car for 24 hours?

Tags: food-safety, meat

can I eat a cryovaced cured ham left in car for 24 hours?  put in car at midnight and taken out the following midnight - mid day temps around 80

Comment: Does the package say "refrigerate"?

Comment: If it says to refrigerate, refer to the duplicate question, cryovaced or not doesn't matter. If it says to not refrigerate, then the car is as good as any other room temperature place and it's safe.